# Close angular material sidenav on any button click inside

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have an Angular 4 Material Sidenav on my application, and it has a bunch of buttons in it, some of which call functions, and others route to other pages.

Outside of having every button call the same function which then looks up what function to call (like with a switch on a param sent in), is there a built-in way to have the sidenav close on child click?

Here's what the sidenav looks like:

```
<md-sidenav #sidenav align="end">
    <br/>
    <span style="margin: 17px">{{auth?.userProfile?.name}}</span> <br />
    <button md-button routerLink="/spells"> All Spells </button> <br />
    <button md-button (click)="login()" *ngIf="!auth.authenticated()">Log In</button>
    <button md-button routerLink="/spellbook" *ngIf="auth.authenticated()"> My Spellbooks </button> <br />
    <button md-button (click)="auth.logout()" *ngIf="auth.authenticated()">Log Out</button>
</md-sidenav>
```

Comment: can you visualize the UI. what does your code look like ?

Comment: Sure, I edited to add the code for the sidenav.  As you can see, there are four buttons, two of which route, and two of which call functions.  I'd like to have all of them close the sidenav when clicked

Answer (score 35):

I saw this question and I found that there is a default event that is tied to the sidenav that you can use. if you put `(click)="sidenav.toggle()"` on anything inside the sidenav (or the sidenav itself) it should close. Here is my code:

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="container">
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
    <p class="menu-item">
      <a routerLink="">
        <button mat-button><mat-icon>dashboard</mat-icon><span> Dashboard</span></button>
      </a>
    </p>
    <p class="menu-item">
      <a routerLink="account">
        <button mat-button><mat-icon>account_circle</mat-icon><span> My Account</span></button>
      </a>
    </p>
    <p class="menu-item">
      <button mat-button><mat-icon>clear</mat-icon><span> Log Out</span></button>
    </p>
  </mat-sidenav>

  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <div id="menu-bar">
      <button mat-button (click)="sidenav.open()" id="menu-button"><mat-icon style="color: #fff;">menu</mat-icon></button>
      <span id="app-title">App Name</span>
    </div>

    <div class="internal-container">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Comment: Nice. This handles keyboard navigation as well.

Comment: I think that to offer a complete answer, it would be necessary to evoke the responsive side of the thing. The closing of the sidenav can be done on mobile with a toggle however, on desktop it does not really make sense. I think that it would be necessary to delocalize the proposed toggle in the typescript file to manage this type of behavior.

Answer (score 7):

Just stumbled onto this, and if you use `(click)="sidenav.mode === 'side' || sidenav.close()` you get closing only if in over mode.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you with two ways.

1.Handle the click event of the button and have your logic in the component.

```
<button md-button  (click)="routeToSpells()"> All Spells </button> <br />
<button md-button (click)="login()" *ngIf="!auth.authenticated()">Log In</button>
<button md-button (click)="reouteToSpellBook()" *ngIf="auth.authenticated()"> My Spellbooks </button> <br />
<button md-button (click)="logout()" *ngIf="auth.authenticated()">Log Out</button>



routeToSpells(){
    this.sidenav.close();
    this.router.navigat('...')
}

login(){
    this.sidenav.close();
    .....
}
reouteToSpellBook(){
    this.sidenav.close();
    this.router.navigat('...')
}

logout(){
    this.sidenav.close();
    this.auth.logout
}
```

Alternatively implement OnDestroy() in the child component and close the side nav at any cause

Answer (score 1):

I just figured this out:

```
<mat-sidenav-container [hasBackdrop]="true">
                <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" class="sideNavigation">
                        <mat-nav-list>
                                <a mat-list-item routerLink="" (click)="sidenav.close()"> bar</a>
                                <a mat-list-item routerLink="/bar" (click)="sidenav.close()">foo</a>
                                <a mat-list-item routerLink="/foo" (click)="sidenav.close()">whatever</a>
                                <a mat-list-item routerLink="/something1" (click)="sidenav.close()">SomePage</a>
                                <a mat-list-item routerLink="/something2" (click)="sidenav.close()">Some Page</a>
                        </mat-nav-list>
                </mat-sidenav>
                <mat-sidenav-content>
                        <mat-toolbar color="accent">
                                <mat-icon (click)="sidenav.toggle()">menu</mat-icon> 
                                <div class="divider"></div>
                                <img class="img" src="../assets/img/logo.png" alt="logo" (click)="goHome()" />
                        </mat-toolbar>
                        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
                </mat-sidenav-content>
        </mat-sidenav-container>
```

Adding `(click)="sidenav.close()"` along with the `routerLink="/whatever/path/here"` works.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `(click)="sidenav.close()"` along with the `routerLink="/whatever/path/here"`
Solution suggested by 'gmauch' worked for me

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32272994)

Answer (score 0):

Let's make this a little more generic, so you don't have to deal with this on every click. I'm assuing most of you want to use the sidenav for navigating to other pages.

So you do:

```html
<div class="nav-container">
  <mat-toolbar color="primary" class="main-toolbar">
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="snav.toggle()"><mat-icon>menu</mat-icon></button>
  </mat-toolbar>

  <mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
    <mat-sidenav #snav [mode]="'over'" [fixedInViewport]="true" fixedTopGap="56" role="navigation">
      <mat-nav-list>
        <mat-list-item routerLink="./home">Home</mat-list-item>
        <mat-list-item routerLink="./page-1">Page x</mat-list-item>
    </mat-sidenav>

    <mat-sidenav-content>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
</div>
```

And in ts:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavigationStart, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { MatSidenav } from '@angular/material/sidenav';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'test';
    private unsubscribe$ = new Subject<void>();

    @ViewChild('snav') snav!: MatSidenav;

    constructor(
        private router: Router
    ) {
        // routing events 
        this.router.events.pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)).subscribe((event: any) => {
            this._navigationInterceptor(event);
        });
    
    }

    private _navigationInterceptor(event: Event): void {
        if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
            this.snav.close();
        }
        
    }
}
```

In that way, the side nav will always close when you change to a new page.
Also notice the `mat-nav-list` and `mat-list-item`, kind of undocumented but it better.